# SlickGrid_AppendNew Row with different Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I m using slickgrid V2.2, I am trying to append new row from the selected row along with data in the selected row. Its working fine, but in the added row the same id generating as the selected row by default. I am using below code. Kindly help me out to append a new row with different id from selectedrow

```
             var row = grid.getDataItem(selectedRow);
                       dataView.addItem(row);
                       grid.render();
                       grid.setSelectedRows([]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` is simply an object containing the columns, so `row.id = {new id};` should work. You'll need to generate the id somehow depending on how your scheme works (don't use the curly brackets around the new id value, I'm just indicating that this value needs to be inserted).

Comment: Hmmm, this is basic javascript. By ```{new id}``` I mean 'you'll have to generate and insert an id here'. ```new id``` would only work if you have a javascript 'class' id that you can instantiate. You're probably using a column of your dataset as the unique ID, so you'll have to work out how to generate an new unique row id. This may be very simple or very complicated depending on how you sync back to the server. I can't do your work for you!